# Malicious email containing PDF attachments

Tags: email, pdf, email-attachments

I'm an university student and I have to do a data mining for a research project. For this reason I need emails containing malicious PDF attachments(I am interested in the .eml files). Where can I find a data corpus like this? Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: At the Universitiy IT Department?

Answer (score 1):

I work at a University Security department. If you want up to date, out in the wild, evil PDF attachments try the CERT of your university (might be called SCIRT depending on where you live). We get them on a daily basis.

You could also try to get that sort of data from the anti-virus suppliers, managed Security Operation Centers (SOC).

You can always dive deep into the darkweb. :)

I am not aware of a up-to-date corpus containing these sort of attachments otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Collaborate with a trusted body is the easiest way. 
Here are some ideas:

1. Check out your university IT department first.
2. Talk to your lecturer on possible collaborations with IT security firms
   that collect these samples.
3. Talk to your lecturer on setting up spam traps/honeypot .
4. Set up your own spam traps/ honeypot.
5. Dig out pastebin, metasploit, etc.

Comment: You mean a honeypot email account? Isn't that just a normal email account? How would pastebin or metasploit help?

Comment: your first 2 point mirror the other answer, your last 3 points do not make a lot of sense

Comment: @schroeder  : I guess the OP can get the those .eml sample from YOU ?

Comment: Yep, he could ask random strangers, too. Although the .eml restriction is a barrier ....

Comment: @schroeder   point no.2 is not repetitive , no sane security firm will risk release sample to unknown third party.   And how much do you know about honeypot (spam trap is part of honeypot) ability ?

Comment: #2 is repetitive, you only add in that you might work with your lecturer. But that's not required. And I'm a honeypot expert. Spam traps are a specialty for *core ISP* email networks. You can do the very same thing as an individual with any normal email account.

Comment: @schroeder   If honeypot works, then : `your last 3 points do not make a lot of sense` ?  point 5 not useful?   
Anything "helpful" from your side?

Comment: What does a honeypot have to do with anything? You are equating honeypots and spam traps, but they do not equate. You tell us how #5 is useful, because I can't see how it is.

Comment: Again, what's the difference between a "spam trap" and any normal email address for a normal user?

Comment: @schroeder  IMHO, spam traps is a subset of honeypot. Bare in mind that, security firms has specialised resource to capture this kinda stuff, I assume a student doesn't have the resources or know where to begin.

Comment: Even for security firms and ISPs, they are just email addresses...